# transform a pandas datetime into a numerical value

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a panda datetime series:

```
>>> desc1.startTime.head()
0   2008-10-18 12:08:49
1   2008-10-18 12:22:52
2   2008-10-18 12:40:26
3   2008-10-18 12:57:52
4   2008-10-18 13:15:17
Name: startTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I would like something like
`t(0)=0` and `t(i) = desc1.startTime(i) - desc1.startTime(0)`

is there a good way to do this with pandas?

EDIT:
This is what I have tried. It's not working

```
>>> desc1.head()
   Wafer_Slot  Summary_GroupName           startTime    LotNum     time
0           1                  1 2008-10-18 12:08:49  Q3968075 00:00:00
1           5                  1 2008-10-18 12:22:52  Q3968075 00:14:03
2          10                  1 2008-10-18 12:40:26  Q3968075 00:31:37
3          15                  1 2008-10-18 12:57:52  Q3968075 00:49:03
4          20                  1 2008-10-18 13:15:17  Q3968075 01:06:28
>>> desc1['time'].head()
0   00:00:00
1   00:14:03
2   00:31:37
3   00:49:03
4   01:06:28
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
>>> desc1['time'].apply(lambda x:x.seconds)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/donbeo/MyApps/phd_python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2169, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/src/inference.pyx", line 1059, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:62578)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object has no attribute 'seconds'
>>>
```

Comment: use `diff()` to subtract rows from each other this will create a timedelta, you can then do `dt.seconds` on the timedelta

Comment: I would like the final result to be  a list of float. How can I do that?

Comment: Why float? what do you want the numbers to represent?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. The value of `t(i)` should be the amount of time passed from the process start that is `startTime[0]`. I do not care what is the final unit as long as proportion is kept.

Comment: So just do `desc1.startTime - desc1.startTime.iloc[0]`

Comment: still I can not get a column of floats. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tolist()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) with [`dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor) and [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) as [Edchum's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997761/transform-a-pandas-datetime-into-a-numerical-value#comment57723997_34997761) says:

```
print df['startTime']
#0   2008-10-18 12:08:49
#1   2008-10-18 12:22:52
#2   2008-10-18 12:40:26
#3   2008-10-18 12:57:52
#4   2008-10-18 13:15:17
#Name: startTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]


print (df['startTime'] - df['startTime'].iloc[0]).dt.seconds.tolist()
#[0, 843, 1897, 2943, 3988]
```

Or you can use converting `timedelta` to `seconds` [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#conversions):

```
print ((df['startTime']-df['startTime'].iloc[0])/np.timedelta64(1, 's')).astype(int).tolist()
#[0, 843, 1897, 2943, 3988]

print (df['startTime']-df['startTime'].iloc[0]).astype('timedelta64[s]').astype(int).tolist()
#[0, 843, 1897, 2943, 3988]
```

If you need `float`, you can omit [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
print ((df['startTime'] - df['startTime'].iloc[0]) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')).tolist()
#[0.0, 843.0, 1897.0, 2943.0, 3988.0]
```

You can use `microseconds`:

```
print (df.startTime - df.startTime.iloc[0]).astype('timedelta64[ms]').astype(int).tolist()
#[0, 843000, 1897000, 2943000, 3988000]
```

**Timing**:

These timings are going to be very dependent on the size of s as well as the number (and position) of values:

```
In [54]: %timeit (df['startTime'] - df['startTime'].iloc[0]).dt.seconds.tolist()
The slowest run took 4.29 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 ms per loop

In [55]: %timeit ((df['startTime'] - df['startTime'].iloc[0]) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')).astype(int).tolist()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.82 ms per loop

In [56]: %timeit (df['startTime'] - df['startTime'].iloc[0]).astype('timedelta64[s]').astype(int).tolist()
The slowest run took 4.31 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop
```